# How to force the http client to not handle the authentication challenges automatically in httpClient 4.3.x?

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am migrating my httpclient 3.x to httpclient 4.3.x.

With httpClient 3.x I used `setDoAuthentication(false)` which ensured that the method would not try to handle the authentication challenges automatically. How can I set the same functionality with httpClient 4.3.x?

I already went through the javadocs of httpmethods and httpclient and there is no way to do it. The closest I have been is the use of `disableAuthCaching()` in httpClientBuilder, but not sure whether it would serve the purpose.

Can anyone please provide some pointers?

I have read somewhere that there is a parameter through which we can achieve this behavior but I am not able to find it anywhere. Sorry if it looks like a pretty basic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it. I guess it can be done by setting the `setDoAuthentication()` method to false in the `requestConfig` for httpClient.

Answer (score 0):

@spock8190 thanks for your post this gave me the correct hint.
But the new method name is `setAuthenticationEnabled` (at least for 4.5)

> Determines whether authentication should be handled automatically.

Example:

```
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("test.de");
    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setAuthenticationEnabled(true).build();
    httpGet.setConfig(requestConfig);
```